# Return array values that are greater than x

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to write a function that returns array values that are greater than or equal to `x`

Here is my code :

```
def threshold(a,x): 
    b = a[x:]
    return b
```

If `x` is `3`, and `a` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`, the function would return `[3,4,5]`

** Forgot to mention that the values might not be sorted. Input could be [1,3,2,5,4], and it would have to return [3,4,5] if x is 3 **

Comment: Is your input sorted, so that just finding a starting index is necessary?

Comment: No, it could be [1, 3, 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using generator expression and [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> def threshold(a, x):
...     return sorted(item for item in a if item >= x)
... 
>>> threshold([1,3,2,5,4], 3)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: How would one add in a.sort into this function? before the return? @falsetru

Comment: `return sorted(item for item in a if item >= x)`

Answer (score 2):

Using built-in function `filter` is an alternative way:

```
def threshold(a, x):
    return filter(lambda e: e>= x, a)

>>> threshold([1, 3, 5, 2, 8, 4], 4)
[5, 8, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version

```
threshold = (lambda a, x :filter(lambda element: element >= x, a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a[a>2]
```

gives

```
array([3,4,5])
```